# Oracle: Can't find any tables in a schema that I know exists

Tags: oracle

First of all, I am almost totally ignorant when it comes to Oracle.  I've dealt with SQL Server for many years, so I am familiar with SQL in general.

I have a Schema (which I think is the equivalent of a database in SQL Server?) and it has tables under it.  I know the tables exist.  I have a linked server connection to them from SQL Server and I see the tables and the data.  I was able to get to these tables before in SQLPlus and SQL Developer using the `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA MySchema` command.

Now when I try to query those tables I get 
`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"`.

I'm logged in with the System account, which is the same account my Linked Server is using, and my understanding was that System should have access to all schemas and tables.

My fear is that I somehow messed up permissions to *System* and it can't see the schema anymore.  Is that possible?

Comment: A schema in Oracle is the equivalent of a schema in SQL Server. The equivalent of SQL Server's database would be a pluggable database in Oracle. But you should never work using the SYSTEM (or SYS) account, that is a really bad idea. What does `select * from dba_tables where owner = 'MYSCHEMA'` return?

Comment: If you're logged in as SYSTEM then you should be able to do `SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS o WHERE o.OWNER = 'your-schema'`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

`select * from dba_tables where owner = 'MYSCHEMA'` returns `no rows selected`.  

`SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS o WHERE o.OWNER = 'your-schema''` lists my tables but with _'_SEQUENCE'_ added to their names.

I tried the following:
`select * from dba_tables where TABLE_NAME like 'MYTABLE%';`-- no rows

`SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS o WHERE o.object_name LIKE 'APPOINTMENT%' ORDER BY 2;`  -- just returned the "_sequence" object I referenced above.  

Again, I can still hit the tables just fine from SQL server using the linked server object.

Comment: And I think this data is in one of those pluggable databases, if that matters.

Comment: What seemed to fix it was changing the service name in my connection in SQL Developer.  Suddenly I'm able to see the tables again in Oracle.  Very odd.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider name resolution as well as access privileges.

You are connected to an account with godlike powers (generally inadvisable, by the way, rather like [logging in as `root` in Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root)), but that on its own doesn't help to resolve a reference to `EMPLOYEES` when it's a table in the `HR` schema (for example). For that you would need to either

- Refer to `HR.EMPLOYEES`, or
- Create a private synonym belonging to the account you'll be using, defining `EMPLOYEES` (or whatever you want) as a reference to `HR.EMPLOYEES`, or
- Create a public synonym, or
- `alter session set current_schema = HR`.

Comment: Thanks William.  When I try that I get the following error: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 22`

Comment: Which one did you try? You need access privileges as well as a name resolution method. Also the pluggable database aspect you just mentioned in a comment could be the problem. Maybe details of the linked server connection will help. What account does it connect to?

Comment: I don't have a multitenant database with multiple PDBs to test with, but you might try querying `cdb_objects` and checking whether your tables exist with an unexpected `CDB$NAME`/`CON$NAME`/`CON_ID`. If you created them in a global administrator schema they may not exist in the expected PDB.

Comment: William, I tried the first one.  What seemed to fix it was changing the service name in my connection in SQL Developer.  Suddenly I'm able to see the tables again in Oracle.  Very odd.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brune not so odd if you were connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: We only have one Oracle instance.  And it only has one user database.  Not sure how I was able to get to the database one day, but I wasn't able to the next.  Maybe had something to do with SID or listener that I couldn't reach?